# Media query for phones

Tags: bootstrap-4, media-queries, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a responsive page using Bootstrap 4.1. When I use google dev tools, and select an iPhone 6, everything displays properly. I have included a field which shows the selected media query in the lower left corner under the 'notes'.

Google dev with iPhone 6 showing correctly and shows 'xs'...
[image]

When viewed on my actual iPhone 6, it is showing 'md'...
[image]

Why would this be happening?

**Edit**
Here is the code to show the current media size...

```
%span.d-sm-none XS
%span.d-none.d-sm-block.d-md-none SM
%span.d-none.d-md-block.d-lg-none MD
%span.d-none.d-lg-block.d-xl-none LG
%span.d-none.d-xl-block XL
```

Comment: You maybe have an concept version of iPhone 6 :D

Comment: I'm confused by what you mean by that.

Comment: how are you checking is it md or xs put your code, maybe its looking for wide mode

Comment: I just edited the post and added the code used to show the media size

Comment: Didi you maybe by accident asked browser for desktop version?

Comment: Did you tested it on another phone besides that one?

Comment: No I haven't. You prompted me to start looking into 'asking for desktop version' and found this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49844216/bootstrap-4-mobile-site-acting-like-desktop. Maybe this is what I need to look into.

Comment: Share if it did

Comment: That was it.... https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/ shows the meta tag for the viewport. Thanks for heading me in the right direction

Comment: No problem, I learned it hard way when ever i get stupid error that has no logic to happen look on the things you never expected to be. Otherwise you wont sleep whole night like me now. Glad it helped ya.